# Is floating point math more precise for values close to unity?

Tags: floating-point, double, precision, physics

#### Question

I've been told many times that floating point arithmetic has the greatest precision if the numbers operated on are close to `1.0` (or sometimes `0.1`). Is there any truth to this?

#### Clearifications

With "arithmetic" I mean things like `a + b`, `a * b`, `a / b`, but also `sqrt(x)` and other mathy functions.

To be specific, let's say that all variables are [IEEE 64 bit double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) floating point numbers.

#### Example

In physics simulation code, physical units are usually incorporated by mapping them to floating point values. Here we have a lot of freedom, but one choice is to go with the [SI/metric system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units), something like

```py
# Base units
m  = 1.0  # metre
s  = 1.0  # second
kg = 1.0  # kilogram
# Derived units
km = 1e+3*m             # kilometre
yr = 60*60*24*365.25*s  # year
m_sun = 1.98841e+30*kg  # mass of the sun
c = 299792458*m/s       # speed of light
...
```

The numerical value of any dimensional variable in such a code depends on the choice of unit system. If we get out a value `x == 1.2e-9` and `x` is meant to be understood as a e.g. a length, we know that this means that `x` is 1.2 nanometres. Had we chosen to set `m = 1e-9`, `x` would instead come out with a value of `1.2`, as we are now working in a unit system where the nanometre is the base length unit.

Depending on the physical system studied within the simulation, different "natural" unit systems might be chosen. If our focus is atomic physics, it's probably not ideal to choose the mass of the sun as the base mass unit. Well why not? That's my question. Sure all masses of interest would then have tiny numerical values, but so what? Would the inherent imprecisions of floating point arithmetic somehow be magnified by working with extremely small/large numbers?

I'm aware that a minimum and maximum floating point number exists (something like `1e-324` and `1e+308`). Using a unit system so out of wack for the task at hand that the values of our variables go beyond these limits is of course destructive. Keeping values well within those bars though, is there really any difference to whether typical values in the code are of order `1.0`, `1e±10`, `1e±100`?

**Note about math functions**

Various math functions are in fact noticeable imprecise given very large/small inputs. As an example, `cos(1e-8) == 1`, i.e. the `cos()` function cannot distinguish positive numbers smaller than `1e-8`. This is *not* relevant to my question, as the input to `cos()` must always be a dimensionless, pure number, i.e. independent of the unit system defined in the code. The same goes for all other trigonometric functions, but also `exp()`, `log()` and others.

Comment: Question: what do *you* mean by *precision* ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Say I want the final result of the computation to have as many correct significant digits as possible. Though double precision has ~16 decimal places, the last decimals of the result (obtained through billions of arithmetic operations, say) cannot be trusted due to what I call floating point "imprecisions". I guess my question is whether the number of trustworthy decimal places is diminished by a bad choice of unit system.

Comment: *to have as many correct significant digits as possible*  Aha, that's what I call *accuracy*, I'm not sure I have anything useful to offer in answer to your question.  But yes, poor choice of unit system can lead to less accurate results than might otherwise be achieved.  As can many other factors.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I never learned to separate *precision* from *accuracy*. :-) So poor choice of unit system *can* mean less accuracy? How so? And how poorly does it need to be in order to affect the accuracy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is floating point math more precise for values close to unity?

Not really.

In general, floating point math well preserves *realtive* precision for `*`, `/`, `sqrt()` cover the lion’s share of the floating point range.  `+`, `-` are subject to significant loss of relative precision (to the result) due to subtraction of nearby values.

Overall, there is little difference for normal numbers for *relative* precision.  It varies from (0.5 to 1.0] * 2<sup>-53</sup>.

The absolute precision changes in steps for powers of 2.

Floating point numbers [0.5...1.0) have the same absolute precision. For `double` 2<sup>-54</sup>.
Floating point numbers [1.0...2.0) have the same absolute precision. For `double` 2<sup>-53</sup>.
Floating point numbers [2.0...4.0) have the same absolute precision. For `double` 2<sup>-52</sup>.
Floating point numbers [4.0...8.0) have the same absolute precision. For `double` 2<sup>-51</sup>.
etc.

> floating point arithmetic has the greatest precision if the numbers operated on are close to 1.0 (or sometimes 0.1). Is there any truth to this?

Values just under a power-of-2 have a higher absolute precision (by about 2x) than values just above a power of 2.

With tiny *subnormal* values, precision is lost, a bit per power of 2 until 0.0 is reached.

---

Advanced: Trig functions has a special concern when their magnitude is large.  A high quality `sin(1e10)` does an internal extended high precision argument reduction to the primary [-pi ... pi] range.  Not all trig function implementations handle this step well.  So for radians arguments, starting in the primary range is useful to maintain precision.  For degree arguments, a simple `fmod(deg, 360.0)` is a simple and precise range reduction.

Comment: There are alternatives to IEEE-754 floating-point arithmetic, such as Posit arithmetic, that do implement higher precision for numbers near unity. See: J. L. Gustafson and I. T. Yonemoto, I.T., "Beating floating point at its own game: Posit arithmetic". *Supercomputing Frontiers and Innovations*, 4(2), April 2017, pp. 71-86. ([online](https://www.superfri.org/superfri/article/download/137/232)) Figure 7 in the paper is instructive.

Comment: Re “`+`, `-` are subject to significant loss of relative precision (to the result) due to subtraction of nearby values”: People say this, but I think it is unfair to the error to blame it for a loss of accuracy when it did not change; the goal did. If x has an error of e, relative error of e/x, and y is near x, then the error in x-y is exactly e, so why are saying it increased in any sense, even relative? If we care about the error relative to x-y, then we should measure it that way all the way through:…

Comment: … When the error in x is e/(x-y) relative to x-y, then the error in x-y is e/(x-y) relative to x-y. It did not change at all! Error should generally not be measured relative to intermediate values, only relative to final outputs or things that we really care about it being relative to. E.g., in an FFT with 1024 outputs, we might not care that some individual element has an error of 10^6 relative to the ideal output value for that element but only care that it has an error of 10^-6 relative to the vector length of the 1024 outputs.